# Completely stop running pyqt5 application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want my pyqt app stop whenever I press "cancel" button. 
For instance this app should be looping features from two tables. I can set a trigger that will always will check it's condition (true/false) depending on pressing the "cancel" button. But is there any way to set the global trigger which will stop application process in any position of code?

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QProgressBar, QLabel)

class Pio(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):

        self.launch = False

        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(20,20,400,50)

        self.okButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.okButton.setGeometry(80, 20, 100, 50)
        self.okButton.move(20, 80)
        self.okButton.setText('launch')

        self.cncl = QPushButton(self)
        self.cncl.setGeometry(300, 20, 100, 50)
        self.cncl.move(320, 80)
        self.cncl.setText('cancel')

        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.start_loop)
        self.cncl.clicked.connect(self.break_loop)
        self.show()

    def start_loop(self):
        if not self.launch:
            self.launch = True
            print ('started!')
            self.loop_numbers()


    def break_loop(self): 
        print ('canceled!')
        if self.launch:
            print ('work in progress....')
            self.launch = False


    def loop_numbers(self):
        print ('running')

        'action #1 that takes a lot of time '
        'action #2 that also takes a lot of time'

        for n in range(101):
            if self.launch:
                self.pbar.setValue(n)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

        for n in range(11):
            if self.launch:
                self.pbar.setValue(n*10)
                time.sleep(0.05)
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Pio()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I move `self.launch` to the beginning of `loop_numbers()` and once loop is started it will be running whe whole process.

Comment: From where do you import `PyQt5`?I think we can't execute your code.

Comment: It is launched from QGIS there is a built-in `PyQt5` module. I edited script so that it should be run.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want. To clarify, you want the program to quit/exit when you press the cancel button?

Comment: @nathancy right. I could set `QApplication.quit()` on cancel button function but it closes QGIS program from which I run my app.

Comment: Have you tried using `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @nathancy it also closes the whole application in which I run my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application will close automatically when the last window is closed so you can try by changing `QWidget` for `QMainWindow` and simply call close from your cancel button.

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QProgressBar


class Pio(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.launch = False

        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(20, 20, 400, 50)

        self.okButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.okButton.setGeometry(80, 20, 100, 50)
        self.okButton.move(20, 80)
        self.okButton.setText('launch')

        self.cncl = QPushButton(self)
        self.cncl.setGeometry(300, 20, 100, 50)
        self.cncl.move(320, 80)
        self.cncl.setText('cancel')

        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.start_loop)
        self.cncl.clicked.connect(self.break_loop)

    def start_loop(self):
        if not self.launch:
            self.launch = True
            print('started!')
            self.loop_numbers()

    def break_loop(self):
        print('canceled!')
        if self.launch:
            print('work in progress....')
            self.launch = False

        # Close window and exit application
        self.close()

    def loop_numbers(self):
        print('running')
        'action #1 that takes a lot of time '
        'action #2 that also takes a lot of time'

        for n in range(101):
            if self.launch:
                self.pbar.setValue(n)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

        for n in range(11):
            if self.launch:
                self.pbar.setValue(n * 10)
                time.sleep(0.05)
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Pio()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```